# How to parse JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing

How to parse this below "choices" on one array means when I have get "id" in array that all id values 108,109.... in 1st index in array but here is the 5 values in choices..so how to parse it

```
choices = (
              {
                  id = 108;
                  label = Distributor;
              },
              {
                  id = 109;
                  label = "Clinical Lab";
              },
              {
                  id = 110;
                  label = Researcher;
              },
              {
                  id = 111;
                  label = "Current Customer";
              },
              {
                  id = 112;
                  label = "Past Customer";
              }
          );
```

Comment: what you want exactly?question was not clear?

Comment: I want to put all "id" in different index in on array

Comment: :Have you got the answer?

Comment: sunny Yes got another solution for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `fast enumeration`.

```
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
// JSONDict is your JSON dict
for (NSDictionary *aDict in JSONDict[@"choices"]) {
    [resultArray addObject:aDict[@"id"]];
}

NSLog(@"%@", resultArray);
```

**Output:**

> (
>       108,
>       109,
>       110,
>       111,
>       112
>   )

Comment: it's work I think, I got another solution for it thx a lot HAS

Answer (score 2):

Get in a single Step bro as

If your array is `NSMutableArray` then use as

```
NSArray *resultArray =  [[NSArray arrayWithArray:temp] valueForKeyPath:@"id"]
```

If simple `NSArray` then use as

```
NSArray *resultArray = [jsonArray valueForKeyPath:@"id"]
```

Comment: This only works if every entry has a id (which may be the case this time)

Comment: He wants the same rite ? Instead of writing three to four lines just made it simple.@ChristianKienle

Comment: I just wanted to point out that your suggested method does not work in any case and I also mentioned that it might work in this case because one can assume that there is always a id. I totally agree with your suggestion for easy cases and this is why I up-vote your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

try like this ,

```
    NSMutableArray *idArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(int i=0;i<[jsonArray count];i++)
        [idArray addObject:[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"id"]];
    NSLog(@"%@",idArray);
```

here you'l get all the values in idArray.

Comment: No this is not work for me but I got another solution for it thx Sunny

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question properly, Then You can try this code for getting Ids in a Array:

```
 NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0;i<[choices count];i++)
    {
        [arr addObject:[[choices objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"]];
    }

    NSLog(@"ID array : %@",arr);
[arr release];
```